# Is there a way to default all the video to html5 player with flash fallback in chrome?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, video, flash, html5

I just switched from Safari to Chrome Canary on OSX (in order to have a 64bit browser).
With Safari (with no flash plugin) videos in some websites (iframes pointing to allmyvid, vk, Vspot and so on) played fine with the HTML5 video player.
Now in Chrome I can only use the flash player (with flashblock to save me from unwanted animations), but I really would like to keep using the html5 player because it seems faster to load the streams.
Is there a way to revert the typical behavior, having HTML5 player by default and then fall back to flash (removing flash plugin is not a good idea since sometimes I still need it)?
I think the solution has to be in the form of an extension or a userscript, but I couldn't find one in my research.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: [see a list of HTML5 extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/html5?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)

Comment: I see your comment only now... those extensions are limited to youtube, vimeo and a few other websites. I however use a workaround now: I added the chrome://plugins bookmark and use it to disable/enable flash when I need it.